# How can I change the background color on my ecwid photos?

Tags: css, wordpress, less, background-color

Hello Im working with ecwid the shopping cart program , Iv uploaded some photos of my products and categories and cant seem to customize the background using css. Everytime I enter a css code for an element , nothing happens

I have tried this:

```
.ecwid-responsive table.ecwid-productBrowser-subcategories-mainTable
 { background-color: black}
```

please go here to see exactly what Im referring to [my website](http://hair.hughesjobs.net/store/)

Comment: you can use background:#000 instead of background-color.

Answer (score 2):

When I add `background: red` to the `element.style {}` in the developer tools (right click > Inspect Element), when I have selected `.ecwid-productBrowser-productsGrid-mainTable`, it works without a problem.

The `table` you are trying to target (`.ecwid-productBrowser-subcategories-mainTable`) is a style of `display: none`, so it's not visible AND it's the wrong table to target (at least on [this page](http://hair.hughesjobs.net/store/#!/Malaysian-Hair/c/15519536/offset=0&sort=normal)).

Answer (score 0):

This is Daria, Ecwid Customer Care Team. I checked your website and as I see, you added "png" images to your category thumbnails. In order to change the background color for these thumbnails you need to add the following code to your active CSS theme in your Ecwid control panel>Settings>Design:

```
table.ecwid-productBrowser-subcategories-mainTable img {
background-color: black !important;
}
```

Then click "Save” (Ctrl+S) and reload the storefront page.

Please, see the screenshot to know how category thumbnails look with this code: http://take.ms/U5oNA Hope, this helps.

Also, if you have any issues with your Ecwid store, you can always contact us directly via email or live chat. You can see all available ways of how you can get help from Ecwid support if you go to your Ecwid Control panel and Click “Get help” link in the right upper corner.

Thank you!